# ERROR: Your wasm-opt version is 91, but we require a version >= 99

Tags: substrate

The following error occurred while building the substrate smart contract:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just install wasm-opt from this [repo](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases/) as per your distro.